# How to fix row with null value showing up in query when it is supposed to be filtered out by WHERE Clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, null, row

I am trying to filter out certain rows that have an EqSt of '1D' or EquipmentStatus. However when I do, on SQL Server, it filters out the rows that have a EqSt of NULL as well. But on Access however, with the exact same query with the exception of != '1D' vs <> '1D', it does not and gives the result desired

I have tried setting ansi nulls on and off and everything

--SQL Server

```
SELECT AssetID ,EqSt
FROM FAC
WHERE (AssetID = '54271' OR AssetID = '52827')
AND EqSt != '1D'
```

vs

--Access

```
SELECT AssetID, EqSt
FROM FAC
WHERE (AssetID = '54271' OR AssetID = '52827')
AND EqSt <> '1D';


SQL Server Result:
-----------------
|AssetID | EqSt |
-----------------
|        |      |
-----------------

Access Result:
------------------
| AssetID | EqSt |
------------------
| 52827   | NULL |
------------------
| 54271   | NULL |
------------------
```

Comment: Perhaps in MS Access, the value is stored as `'NULL'` and not as the special value `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT 
  AssetID ,
  EqSt 
 FROM FAC 
 WHERE 
     (AssetID = '54271' OR AssetID = '52827') 
       AND    
     (  EqSt is null   OR    EqSt <> '1D')
```

Comment: Alternatively you can also do isnull(EqSt,'1D') = '1D'.

Comment: Thanks that worked, Im curious why I would have to use EqSt is null though. Shouldn't null values still be included in the WHERE clause with just the EqSt <> '1D'?